# Keep reference of views from collectionView is doubled

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Trying to keep reference in arrays of all views that being added to collection view .

So what happens, is that i have this array with the data, but when i scroll down the collection, it calls the reusable cells function ,and try to add them again to my array ,although i am checking if they are there before adding them again :

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 UICollectionViewCell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

 //quantity
    UILabel *quantityL=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width/10,cell.frame.size.width/10, cell.frame.size.width/5,cell.frame.size.width/5)];
    quantityL.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",quantity];
    quantityL.font=[UIFont fontWithName:[Globals sharedGlobals].titleFont size:[Globals sharedGlobals].badgeSize];
    quantityL.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
  //more and more stuff

 [cell addSubview:quantityL]; //add to cell
    if(![allQuantities containsObject:quantityL])  //check if already in array!
    [allQuantities addObject:quantityL];  //add to array
```

i can see that `allQuantities` array is changing its size... why ?

Comment: oh i see, everytime i create the label , its getting a new address so its not inside the array...so how would i manage this thing right ?

Comment: I'm sorry but this is really horrible code. Your label won't resize correctly. You should subclass `UITableViewCell`, add there a label and use `layoutSubview` function to set your frame (or use `autolayout` with `storyboards`). Then `dequeue` the cell in your `tableview`. I wouldn't accept such code in review, it's just wrong in any terms. Why do you want to keep `UIViews` in an array? This seems to be wrong app architecture.

Comment: ok ok , its horrible its horrible and you are the best. So there is someone who doesn't know how to do it right, this is why he is here, so instead of keep telling me stuff in the air, maybe you can show me how to do that right with an answer ?? ( i am doing it all in code, no story board and by the way it works great)

Comment: i keep them in array so i can do special stuff with them like animate them in ways you dont know yet . Dont be so arrogant ,there are things people do with a reason  . if you want to do special things, its not always right by your book.

Comment: I just told you- you should subclass UITableViewCell and dequeue it. I can add a sample if you wish to, however I don't think my critic was without any help to you - it was without sample code but included all required steps, which you can find on any tutorial page. Anyway, I'll write it.

Comment: @Vive btw - i do subclass it ! check the edit.

Comment: It's you who seem to be arrogant. As I told, I've wrote each step how to do it properly and in fact did criticise, but you could learn from it. I also don't claim that keeping views in array is wrong in your case, but in 99% it's totally unnecessary. So I've ASKED why do you need to keep it in array, not criticise it.

Comment: thank you man. Your answer is too vague for me, i dont really know whats wrong with adding views to cells the way i did. I think this is the way you do it,if not, please post code.

Comment: and its still not solving the problem to keep pointers only for new labels, and not keep adding them to the array again and again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly reuse and set frames: code for your controller:

```
#define kMyCellIdentifier @"kMyCellIdentifier"

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
    [self.collectionView setDelegate:self];
    [self.collectionView setDataSource:self];
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[MyCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:kMyCellIdentifier];
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionViewDelegate && UICollectionViewDataSource

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kMyCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.textLabel setText:@"blah"];

    return cell;
}
```

And your cell subclass:

```
@interface MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

@property(nonatomic, readonly) UILabel *textLabel;

@end

@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        _textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        [self.textLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.textLabel];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect rect = self.contentView.bounds;

    [self.textLabel setFrame:rect];
}
```

Comment: @Curnelious Ok, so here's a little code snippet how to do it. Now, as this doesn't answer your question and we may find a better solution, can you tell +- why would you like to keep reference to each label?

Comment: thanks so the labels i am adding i will add now inside the mycollectionviewcell class , inside the initwithframe method ?

Comment: i am keeping reference of them because while you scroll all the images, labels and other stuff on the collection are being animated each in a different way , so i have to save a pointer to the labels,images,etc..

Comment: @Curnelious That's part of your model data isn't it?  There is no need to store that information in the view.  You need to embrace MVC.

Comment: i am not sure i understand you . my MVC is not having one place with all my specific views that i want, (not all of them,only some of them) in one array...

Comment: @Curnelious So the same way you deceide how to animate it for the first time, you should use later to animate it again. You can use `collectionView:willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:` delegate method to find out what to animate. Also refer here to know what's MVC, because (unless I understood you wrong) you don't know atm: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html

Comment: sorry i am not getting something, i have an array of data, in which i am loading from it the data to the collection , so every view in the cell, is derived from this data. Question is, the MyCell class, dont know about this data array , so how would i correctly let it know about it ?

Comment: @Curnelious Why would you? Model should keep data. View should keep these visual things like labels and layout. Controller should manage the flow between model and view. So your controller should set any data from your model to your view (from array to cell). Eg like I've shown in `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can set text of your view(cell) from your model(array) in controller.

Comment: In the cell class, i would like to create labels, and images, depend on the cell number, and some data array , so till now, i did :         NSDictionary *dataToBuildViewFrom=[data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; , now i have to put this line in the cell class right  ? but how would i have the row ?

Comment: @Curnelious No, your cell should not contain any data - thats `MVC`. Read that, 2 people suggested it so it seems you should ;). You create `UILabels`, `UIImageViews` etc basing on code I've presented above. In your controller you should refer to that `UILabel`, `UIImageView` etc in in mentioned above method you should set texts of labels, images of imageViews. Your cell should NOT set any text, image or nothing. It should know nothing about the data.

Comment: @Curnelious Glad to help ^^. In case of problems if you'd like me to help with another question, mention me in the comments, so I'll look into it. Sorry for being so strict, you had 2k rep, so I thought you have bigger experience and just don't care about the code quality. Anyway, I'd suggest you to browse some RayWenderlich pages, it's a great database for sorting things out with MVC and other patterns.

Comment: @Vive ok thanks a lot .I do have some things that are not entirely clear, for example, in the cell class, where i add the views, some of them are depend on the data model, so for example if the data model say x , i am adding the view in some place, otherwise in another place. So if i don't have my data model inside the cell class, how can i know these things ? the whole cell structure depends on the data.. (btw,i know ray for years,thanks for that.)

Comment: @Curnelious Then you should add a flag eg shouldPlaceImageOnRight and set this flag from your controller. Then in layoutSubviews consider this flag and place the view on desired place.

Comment: @Vive oh ok got it. thanks a lot. i have change my whole code according to yours and it worked great. the only thing remains is, how can you loop over all of your images on all cells from the main controller (this is why i kept array of them and now i wouldn't have access to them without it)